# New QGradient type. How?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Hello is it possible to create my own QGradient type ? for example we have QLinearGradient, but I need also different types such as Exponential Up, Bump, Spike, Exponential Down. What the best way to do it ?

Comment: How about subclassing `QGradient`? Could you post a sample of the code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Since the python QGradiant object wraps a C++ variant of the same, which in turn may map to hardware or graphics driver support, I imagine the Linear type you have there is all you're going to get from a general point of view. But you can always synthesize these using the linear gradient. Here's (untested) example of making a red gradient that applies a square to skew the gradient's progression.

```
gradient = QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(200, 200))
for index in range(101):
    f = index / 100.0
    gradient.setColorAt(f, QColor((f ** 2) * 255, 0, 0, 255))
```

Comment: hm. how can I guess what type is that ?

Comment: It's not any of the types you mentioned, it's just one I made up. You'll have to determine the function that maps the range 0 to 1.0 to whatever desired output you want. I assume that the algorithms for "Bump" and "Spike" are documented somewhere.